Prop 1.3 in "Birational geometry of algebraic varieties": specialization of rational curves
I have a couple of questions about some arguments in proof of Proposition 1.3 from Birational geometry of algebraic varieties by Kollár and Mori (p 8):

Proposition 1.3. [Abh56, Prop. 4] Let $X$ be smooth of any dimension
and $f: Y \to X$ a proper birational morphism. For any $x \in X$, either
$f^{-1}(x)$ is a point or $f^{-1}(x)$ is covered by rational curves.


Proof: Let us consider first the case when $X$ is a surface.
We resolve the indeterminacies of $f^{-1}$ by successively blowing-up
points of $X$. (-> Q A) At each step we introduce a $\Bbb{P}^1$. Thus every $f^{-1}$ is dom-
inated by a union of some of these $\Bbb P^1$s. By Lüroth's Theorem, every  $f^{-1}$ is a union of rational curves.


The general case can be proved the same way provided we know how
to resolve indeterminacies of maps. However a much weaker version of
resolution is sufficient. Since we will use (1.3) later only when $X$ is a
surface, we only sketch the proof in the higher-dimensional case.
We may assume that $Y$ is normal. The exceptional set of $f$ is of pure
codimension one by [Sha94, II.4.4] (see also (2.63)). Let $E \subset Y$ be an
irreducible component of the exceptional set. At a general point $e \in E $, the pair $(Y, E)$ is isomorphic to a succession of blow ups with smooth centers by
(2.45).
Thus there is a rational curve  that passes through $e$ such that
$f(C)$ is a point. Since a rational curve can specialize only to unions of
rational curves, (-> Q B) there is a rational curve through ever

Questions:
(A): Just to clarify, when in case of $X$ surface is refered to "resolving indeteriminancies of $f^{-1}$ by blowing up points of $X$" is it meant the following "road": For $f:X \to Y$ one has the graph $\Gamma_f \subset X \times Y$ obtained as as closure of (topol.) image of $(id,f): X \to X \times Y$ endowed with reduced scheme structre. Then one blows up $X$ successively at points until their composition map $B: X' \to X$ admits "natural" birational factorization trough $\Gamma_f$, right?
If not, can it be made in precise terms what meant by procedure to "resolve indeteriminancies of $f^{-1}$ by blowing up points"?
(B): For higher dimensional $X$ it is stated for pair $(Y,E)$ ($E$ irred comp of exceptional locus) that a rational curve $C \subset E$ can only "specialize" to a union of rational curves.
What is meant here by "specialization" of a rational curve? I know the notion of specialization for points ($p$ is specialization of $q$ iff it is contained in closure of $q$), but what is meant by "specialization" of rational here as stated here and why a rational curve can only specialize in this sense to union of rationals? Is it somehow "obvious" or wellknown (...as the authors not refer to an explicit result)?
#UPDATE: So far I understand by specialization of $C$ should be interpreted in "moduli" sense as that there is a flat family $h: D \to B$ where base scheme $B$ is a smooth curve such that general fibre $D_b$ of $h$ is $\cong C$ and for a closed point $b_0 \in B$ one then says that $C$ "specializes to" $D_{b_0}$.
But then - if acually thats what is meant by specialization of $C$ - why ration $C$ can only specialize to a union of rational curves as claimed in the proof?

This is also discussed very nicely in Olivier Debarre’s book, “Higher dimensional algebraic geometry.”  So you might check there for a different perspective (it is also in an appendix of Koll’ar’s “Rational curves on algebraic varieties” and in the book by Corti — Koll’ar — Smith).

Related also with this and Proposition 7.3 in Debarre's notes

@JasonStarr: sorry for digging this old, but I'm not sure to which amount Debarre's book elaborates this statement about that a rational curve can only degenerate to union of rational curves of smaller degree. Indeed, in proof of Lemma 3.7 (p 68) (book) resp. Lemma 7.8 (linked notes) he only states this as fact, but looking through prev chapter I haven't found an elaboration. Do you maybe know if this can be immediately deduced from some of earlier results from this book? The starting point should be that the arithmetic genus not changes along flat family if general fibers are "nice enough".

But does it imply the claim? Eg, why cannot be the one of the reduced components of the degeneration be an elliptic curve?

@JasonStarr: ..ah, and also I noticed that this result I quoted on constancy of arithmetic genus along flat family from Hartshorne, Cor. III.9.13 requires every fibre to be normal, but if special fibre is union of curves intersecting nontrivially (so connected, but not irred) then this result not applies
